# Flex Layout with React Native

Tags: react-native, layout, flexbox

I'm having an issue where my container is collapsing on my child components which consists of a list of 4 images and one icon at the end of the container in a row.  If I set the height explicitly then I can make it large enough to fit the content for one device.  However, I have the images resizing themselves right now based off of width of the phone and a percent and then scaling to conserve aspect ratio.  Is there a way to make my container grow just large enough to ensure it fits its child components when its child components scale based off of device width?

I thought that React Native flex default was to do this but for whatever reason my container is not fitting the images inside it but instead shrinking and all inside content is shrinking down except the images which lay over the top of my now shrunk containers.

```
    export default function BadgeQuickView() {
    return (   
        <View style={styles.badgeViewContainer}>
            <View style={styles.badgeContainerTop}>
                <View style={styles.badgeContainerLeftBorder}></View>
                <Text style={styles.badgeContainerTitle}>FEATURED BADGES</Text>
                <View style={styles.badgeContainerRightBorder}></View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.quickBadgeList}>
                {TEST_BADGE_ARRAY.map(option => (
                    <View style={styles.badgeInfoContainer} key={option.id}>
                        <Image style={styles.badgeImage} source={{uri: option.url}} fadeDuration={0} />
                        <Text style={styles.badgeDescText}>{option.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                ))}
                <View style={styles.moreBadgesButtonContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.moreBadgesButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.moreBadgesText}>All {`\n`} Badges</Text>
                        <Entypo name={'dots-three-horizontal'} size={moderateScale(20)} color={profileColors.editProfileText}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    badgeViewContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: moderateScale(130),
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderColor: userInterface.borderColor,
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        paddingBottom: 5
    },
    moreBadgesText: {
        color: 'black',
        fontFamily: 'montserrat',
        fontSize: moderateScale(8),
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: profileColors.editProfileText,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },  
    badgeDescText: {
        color: 'black',
        fontFamily: 'montserrat',
        fontSize: moderateScale(8),
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: profileColors.editProfileText,
        textAlign: 'center',
    }, 
    quickBadgeList: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        paddingLeft: 15,
    },
    badgeImage: {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: undefined,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        marginBottom: 10,
    },  
    moreBadgesButton: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },  
    moreBadgesButtonContainer: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '15%',
    },
    badgeInfoContainer: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '20%',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        padding: 5,
    },
    badgeContainerTop: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    badgeContainerLeftBorder: {
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderColor: userInterface.borderColor,
        borderTopWidth: 2,
        width: '5%',
        bottom: moderateScale(13) / 2,
    },
    badgeContainerTitle: {
        fontFamily: 'montserrat-bold',
        color: profileColors.editProfileText,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        fontSize: moderateScale(13),
        bottom: moderateScale(13) /2,
    },
    badgeContainerRightBorder: {
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderColor: userInterface.borderColor,
        borderTopWidth: 2,
        width: '100%',
        bottom: moderateScale(13) / 2,
    },
});
```

** Edit:  Added current working code for reference.  `moderateScale(...)` is just taking the screenHeight and scaling the height and working for most devices that I have tested thus far.  I would like to not have to set this explicitly though if possible and instead have it expand based on its content.

Below is the desired and undesired looks.  When I comment out the height: from the view container and set it to flex it won't expand to fit its content.  When real images are added in the images show over the top of the bottom border and the text is not visible at all that will show under the red box typically.  Added the red just as an indicator of where the image and text renders.
[image: Desired Look]

[image: Undesired Look]

Comment: share some code reference so that anyone can help

Comment: Yeah. Just as @abhikumar22 mentioned, please share what you've done and what it should like when it works as expected.

Comment: @SylvaElendu Added code and images to show desired result.

Comment: @abhikumar22 Added code and images to show desired result.